# Inhibit macro expansion

Tags: c++

Is there any way to inhibit preprocessor macro expansion?  I have an existing C header file that uses `#define` to define a set of integers and I would like to copy it to a C++ enum that has the same value names.  For example (using C++11):

```
enum MyEnum {
  VALUE,
  // ...
};

#define VALUE 0

MyEnum convert(int x) {
  if (x == VALUE) {
    return MyEnum::VALUE;
  }
  // ...
}
```

The problem of course is that `MyEnum::VALUE` gets translated to `MyEnum::0`, which causes a syntax error.  The best solution is to replace the macros with enums, but unfortunately that is not an option in my situation.

I tried to use concatenation, but that didn't help (the compiler gave the same error).

```
#define CONCAT(a,b) a##b
// ...
return MyEnum::CONCAT(VA,LUE);  // still results in MyEnum::0
```

Is there another solution that allows me to have the same name for the macro and for the enum value?

Comment: The longstanding convention is that ALL UPPERCASE is used for macros, and everything else uses at least one lowercase letter. I.e. `enum MyEnum { Value }`.

Answer (score 3):

You can undefine a macro:

```
#undef VALUE
```

after including the header.

Comment: Note that this will make the macro undefined for the rest of the file, so if the macro is to be used later in the source then it has to be redefined.